# How to investigate convernegce of $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{(2x)^n}{x^2n+\frac{70}{n}}$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I need to investigate convergence and absolute convergence of series
$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{(2x)^n}{x^2n+\frac{70}{n}}$$
depending on the value of the parameter $x \in \mathbb{R}$

I think use here Root test $$\lim_{n \to +\infty} \sqrt[n]{\left| \frac{(2x)^n}{x^2n+\frac{70}{n}}\right| } = 2x $$
Okey, for $x >\frac{1}{2}$ series is divergent and for $x <\frac{1}{2}$ is converges absolutly, but what about $x = \frac{1}{2}$ ?

So for $x = \frac{1}{n}$ should be
$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{\frac{n}{4} + \frac{70}{n}} $$
I think it is diverges by the comparison test. If I take $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{n}$ it will be right?

Comment: Using the ratio test:

$$\lim_{\text{n}\to\infty}\left|\frac{\left(\frac{\left(\text{a}x\right)^{\text{n}+1}}{\left(\text{n}+1\right)x^{\text{n}+1}+\frac{70}{\text{n}+1}}\right)}{\left(
\frac{\left(\text{a}x\right)^\text{n}}{\text{n}x^\text{n}+\frac{70}{\text{n}}}\right)}\right|=\left|\text{a}x\right|\cdot\lim_{\text{n}\to\infty}\left|\frac{\text{n}x^\text{n}+\frac{70}{\text{n}}}{\left(\text{n}+1\right)x^{\text{n}+1}+\frac{70}{\text{n}+1}}\right|\tag1$$

Comment: You have a typo before your last displayed formula. "So for $x = \frac{1}{n}$" should be "… for $x = \frac{1}{2}$". And the formula in the title doesn't match the one in the body. In the title, you have $x^n n$ in the denominator, in the body it's $x^2n$. Assuming the formula in the body is right: Yes, for $x = \frac{1}{2}$ the terms behave essentially like $\frac{4}{n}$, so comparison with $\frac{1}{n}$ is a good way to show divergence. What happens for $x = -\frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: Thank you so much. So for $x = -\frac{1}{n}$ we have $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{\frac{n}{4}+\frac{70}{n}}$ and this series is converges by the Alternating series test, because $\lim_{n \to +\infty} \frac{1}{\frac{n}{4} + \frac{70}{n}} = 0$ and this sequence is monotonic

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{\frac{n}{4} + \frac{70}{n}}>\sum_{n=18}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{\frac{n}{4} + \frac{70}{n}}>\sum_{n=18}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{\frac{n}{2}}=\infty$$so this series is divergent for $x=\dfrac{1}{2}$